# Passing a parameter to a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameter-passing

I have a problem using threads. There is a class like this:

```
public class MyThread
{
    public void Thread1(int a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            j++;
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 1000; i1++)
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Done From Class");
    }
}
```

and I use this below code for using it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyThread thr = new MyThread();
    Thread tid1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(thr.Thread1));

    tid1.Start();
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

I get error because of Thread1 Parameter (int a), 
there isn't any problem when I haven't got any parameter.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Side note: Do not use Threads. You will need them very rarely. Use Tasks and ThreadPool.

Comment: You have a class named `MyThread` that is decidedly not a `Thread`; hopefully this was just an example.

Comment: Henk Holterman, why not using thread ? assume i have button which is doing something in one minute, unfortunately during it's job my windows application is completely dead .. is there any other solution for handling such as problem ?

Answer (score 0):

A preferred method is the first one as you can pass multiple parameters to your method without having to cast to object all the time.

```
Thread t= new Thread(() => thr.Thread1(yourparameter));
t.Start();
```

Alternatively, you need to use `parameterised` thread as you are passing parameter to thread. you can also do

```
Thread t = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(thr.Thread1));
t.Start (yourparameter);
```

ofcourse your parameter has to be of object type for second example.

Answer (score 0):

Threads accept a single `object` parameter:

```
public void Thread1(object a1)
{
    int a = (int)a1;
    ...
}
```

Pass it like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(Thread1);
t.Start(100);
```

You don't normally need to build delegates. Doing `new ThreadStart(...)` is normally useless from C# 2.0 .

Another (common) solution is to put `Thread1` in another object:

```
public class MyThread
{
    public int A;

    public void Thread1()
    {
        // you can use this.A from here
    }
}

var myt = new MyThread();
myt.A = 100;
var t = new Thread(myt.Thread1)
t.Start();
```

This because delegates have a reference to the containing object of the method. Clearly in this way you lose access to the caller's object... But then you could do:

```
public class MyThread
{
    public int A;
    public CallerType ParentThis;

    public void Thread1()
    {
        // you can use this.A from here
        // You can use ParentThis.Something to access the caller
    }
}

var myt = new MyThread();
myt.A = 100;
myt.ParentThis = this;
var t = new Thread(myt.Thread1)
t.Start();
```

A final common method is to use closures, as suggested by `Ehsan Ullah` (the example with the `() =>`)

Comment: does it mean i must have just one parameter as object ? what about having multiple parameter ?

Comment: @Farshad There is `new object[] { par1, par2, par3 }`  for this... Or `Tuple.Create(par1, par2, par3)`, or the special class method, or the closure method. It isn't a showstopper, only a showslower :-)